# How are files run in a Files folder in an ansible Role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, ansible-role

I have an ansible playbook, deploy_app_prod.yml, that calls the app_beanstalk ansible role

```
├── app_beanstalk
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   ├── files
│   │   │   ├── extensions
│   │   │   │   ├── 01_addLocalDNS.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 02_resources.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 03_cloudwatch.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 03_option_settings.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 04_properties.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 04_tail_logs.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 05_s3fs.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 06_scripts.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 06_tomcat_ssl.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 07_cron_jobs.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 10_amazon_aide.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 10_amazon_harden.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 10_aws_inspector.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 10_tomcat7_harden.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 11_scheduled_scaling.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 12_update_tomcat_config.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 13_cloudwatch_alarms.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 14_apache_server.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 90_security_fixes.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 90_setup_iptables.config
│   │   │   │   ├── 99_deepsecurityagent.config
│   │   │   │   ├── afp.properties.Portal-Admin
│   │   │   │   ├── afp.properties.Portal-Live
│   │   │   │   ├── afp.properties.Portal-PCP
│   │   │   │   ├── afp.properties.Portal-Util
│   │   │   │   ├── afportal_cron_jobs.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── bin
│   │   │   │   │   ├── get_aws_instance_id.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── link-checker-configuration.properties
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_alerts.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_client.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_encryption_utility.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_image_retriever.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_link_checker_external_validations.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_link_checker_internal_validations.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_link_checker_notification.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_link_checker_update_indexer.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_load_alerts.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_mv_apache_logs.sh
│   │   │   │   │   ├── run_mv_autonomy_xml_files.sh
│   │   │   │   │   └── run_survey_update_utility.sh
│   │   │   │   ├── header.jsp
│   │   │   │   ├── httpd
│   │   │   │   │   ├── conf
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── httpd.conf
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── mime.types
│   │   │   │   │   └── conf.d
│   │   │   │   │       └── elasticbeanstalk
│   │   │   │   │           ├── 00_application.conf
│   │   │   │   │           ├── 02_static.conf
│   │   │   │   │           ├── af_portal.conf
│   │   │   │   │           └── stig.conf
│   │   │   │   └── server.xml
│   │   │   └── s3fs-fuse-master.zip
│   │   ├── handlers
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   ├── meta
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── inventory
│   │   │   └── test.yml
│   │   └── vars
│   │       └── main.yml
```

However, none of the files explicitly call any of these .config or .sh files in the files folder, yet the prod environment gets configured correctly in the aws hosted platform when a jenkins job is run on demand executing the deploy_app_prod.yml file. I don't understand how these .config files or .sh files get executed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The culprit was a module with_filetree:

```
 name: Create Template files
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "/var/tmp/{{application_name}}_{{ version }}/app/.ebextensions/{{ item.path }}"
  with_filetree:
    - extensions/
  when: item.state == 'file'
```